# Rationalising package structure in python

Tags: python, packaging

I am developing a python library with the following structure

```
/application
  /lib
  __init__.py
    /models
    __init__.py
    model1.py
    model2.py
    model3.py
```

In each model%.py file there is a corresponding class named Model%. I like to keep these classes in their own files but it means that in my application I need to import classes from the models package like so

```
from models.model1 import Model1
from models.model2 import Model2
from models.model3 import Model3
```

Is there some way to do this instead?

```
from models import Model1, Model2, Model3
```

It feels more intuitive and more like what I am doing. I have a package called models and I want it to contain these classes but I still want each class to have its own file so I can add new models by simply adding a file.

Previously I put this in my /application/lib/models/_*init*_py file

```
from model1 import Model1
from model2 import Model2
from model3 import Model3
```

But I understood this was importing all the classes even when I only need one of them

Comment: Its truly a matter a choice- I've numerous different people say they like to keep `__init__.py` empty or only do basic init stuff.  You could define an `__all__` in `__init__.py` and than, `from models import *`

Answer (score 2):

Your final solution is correct. You should only worry about loading too many classes if it is causing serious performance issues, which I highly doubt.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a file in your models directory that imports your classes, then import from that file.  For example, you could create a file called `api.py` that contains

```
from model1 import Model1
from model2 import Model2
from model3 import Model3
```

Then you could import the models like this

```
from models.api import Model1, Model2, Model3
```

Comment: You could do this same thing in the `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

Create separate package for each module. Put `model1.py` into `model1` package. In `__init__.py` file of `model1` package, put

```
from model1 import Model1
```

then, you will be able to do

```
from model1 import Model1
```

from your application.